# zsh: how to get associative array length?

Tags: zsh

As seen in another post for arrays, I tried this:

```
test[1]="hello"
test[7]="foo"
test[3]="world"
echo ${#test[@]}
7
```

But it gives me the last index of the associated array.

How to get the length of my associated array?

Comment: That's a plain array with 7 elements (no sparse arrays in zsh). You need `typeset -A test` to set the type to *associative array*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you had run `typeset -A test` beforehand, that will have assigned elements of a plain array, not an associative array.

zsh arrays like the arrays of most shells and languages (the only exception that I know is ksh (and bash which copied ksh's array design)) are not sparse.

If you set elements of index 1 and 7 without setting the elements of index 2 to 6, that will still allocate an array with 7 elements, the ones from 2 to 6 being set to the empty string.

So, that code is equivalent to:

```
test=(hello '' world '' '' '' foo)
```

You can confirm it with:

```
$ typeset -p test
typeset -a test=( hello '' world '' '' '' foo )
```

Now, with:

```
$ typeset -A test
$ test[1]=hello test[7]=foo test[3]=world test[03]=zeroworld
```

same as

```
typeset -A test=(
  1  hello
  7  foo
  3  world
  03 zeroworld
)
```

Recent versions also support:

```
typeset -A test=(
   [1]=hello
   [7]=foo
   [3]=world
  [03]=zeroworld
)
```

For compatibility with ksh93 / bash.

You would define it as an associative array (keys being arbitrary sequences of bytes, not numbers, though you're free to interpret as numbers if you wish), and

```
$ print -r -- $#test $test[3] $test[03]
4 world zeroworld
```

If you wanted to count the number of elements of a plain array that are not the empty string, you could do:

```
$ typeset -a test=()
$ test[1]=hello test[7]=foo test[3]=world
$ (){print $#} $test
3
```

Here relying on the fact that unquoted parameter expansions elide empty elements (to help compatibility with ksh).

Compare with:

```
$ (){print $#} "$test[@]"
7
```

(reminiscent of the Bourne shell's `"$@"`) which doesn't elide them.

You could elide them explicitly as well with the `${array:#pattern}` operator which removes elements that match a pattern:

```
$ (){print $#} "${test[@]:#}"
3
```

Note that `${#array[@]}` is the Korn shell syntax. In `zsh`, you can use `$#array` like in csh (though it also supports the Korn syntax).